# I need to load the content of Multiselect component dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I have the content (states) in data?.[0]?.location and trying to load this in Multiselect component as below.

```
                <Multiselect
                  displayValue="location"
                  showCheckbox
                  selectedValues={checked}
                  options={
                    data?.[0]?.location.map((item, index) => (index, item.state))
                    
                    // data?.[0]?.location
                  }
                  onSelect={(event) => {
                    setChecked(event);
                  }}
                  value={checked}
                  style={{
                    multiselectContainer: {
                      boxShadow: "0px 3px 6px #00000029",
                    },
                    searchBox: {
                      minHeight: 54,
                      PaddingTop: 10
                    }
                  }}

                />
```

With the above code the Multiselect box does not show the content (state names) but just the checkboxes. To address this I am trying to save the content of data?.[0]?.location into a const variable with following code,

```
           const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([]);

             const getLocation = () => {
                try {
                   alert("CALLED")
                  // if (data?.[0]?.location.map) {
                   // const res = data?.[0]?.location.map();
                  const res = data?.[0]?.location.map((item, index) => (index, 
                  item.state))
                  setChecked(res?.data);
                  console.log(res?.data)
                   return res;
                 // }
               } catch (err) {
                       throw err;
               }
            };
            console.log(checked)
```

But this does not work.

Comment: are you using any library ?

Comment: I am using multiselect-react-dropdown